Receiving multicast video on windows 10
I'm currently trying to enable multicast streaming from a camera. The camera is on ip 192.168.1.178 streaming rtp h264 on 224.0.0.251:11024. I'm able to see the video stream on Linux and Android devices in my app but on windows I can't see it. I'm also unable to connect to the stream in VLC. However I can see the data in wireshark.
wireshark
Below is my ip table
IP table
I've ensured all of my virtual network drivers are disabled.
Any help or ideas is appreciated thank you.
